# What is the nearest Hindu term for "numinous"?

Tags: terminology

Wikipedia gives following information for [Numinous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numinous):

> Numinous (/ˈnjuːmɪnəs/) is an English adjective, derived from the Latin numen, meaning "arousing spiritual or religious emotion; mysterious or awe-inspiring".[1] The term was popularized by the German theologian Rudolf Otto in his influential 1917 German book Das Heilige, which appeared in English as The Idea of the Holy in 1923.

Another definition is

> having a strong religious or spiritual quality; indicating or suggesting the presence of a divinity.

When Ramakrishna Paramahamsa went into Samadhi, people in the room must have felt the numinous.

Is there a word in Hindu scripture for this?

Comment: Maybe the word is Bhakti?

Comment: It's called Brahma Tejas.

Comment: Jagriti of Ashtasaatvika Bhaava

Answer (score 1):

The numinous is described by his brother when J Krishnamurti achieved enlightenment:

http://www.bernie.cncfamily.com/k_enlight_nitya.htm

> "The place seemed to be filled with a Great Presence and a great longing came upon me to go on my knees and adore, for I knew that the Great Lord of all our hearts had come Himself; and though we saw  Him not, yet all felt the splendour of His presence.
>
> Then the eyes of Rosalind were opened and she saw. Her face changed as I have seen no face change, for she was blessed enough to see with physical eyes the glories of that night. Her face was transfigured, as she said to us, 'Do you see Him, do you see Him?' for she saw the divine Bodhisattva [the Lord Maitreya], and millions wait for incarnations to catch such a glimpse of our Lord, but she had eyes of innocence and had served our Lord faithfully. And we who could not see saw the Splendours of the night mirrored in her face pale with rapture in the starlight.
>
> Never shall I forget the look on her face, for presently I who could not see but who gloried in the presence of our Lord felt that He turned towards us and spoke some words to Rosalind; her face shone with divine ecstasy as she answered, 'I will, I will,' and she spoke the words as if they were a promise given with splendid joy. Never shall I forget her face when I looked at her; even I was almost blessed with vision. Her face showed the rapture of her heart, for the innermost part of her being was ablaze with His presence but her eyes saw. And silently I prayed that He might accept me as His servant and all our hearts were full of that prayer. In the distance we heard divine music softly played, all of us heard though hidden from us were the Gandharvas. [Cosmic angels who make the music of the spheres.]
>
> The radiance and the glory of the many Beings present lasted nearly an half hour and Rosalind, trembling and almost sobbing with joy, saw it all; "Look, do you see?" she would often repeat, or "Do you hear the music?" Then presently we heard Krishna's footsteps and saw his white figure coming up in the darkness, and all was over"

Rig Veda 10 76 1

> आ व रञ्जस ऊर्जां वयुष्टिष्विन्द्रं मरुतो रोदसीनक्तन |
>   उभे यथा नो अहनी सचाभुवा सदः-सदोवरिवस्यात उद्भिदा ||
>
> 1. I GRASP at you when power and strength begin to dawn: bedew ye, Indra and the Maruts, Heaven and Earth,
>       That Day and Night, in every hall of sacrifice, may wait on us and bless us when they first spring forth.

Hindi/Sanskrit ऊर्जा  (urja = power,strength) represents a good approximation to the manifestation of the numinous.

Comment: You should add this in question and not an answer. It looks like you are not sure if the term is correct. Any guesses etc., should go into the question only.